# Does SQL Server 2012 support Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, kerberos

In our Java application we need to connect to SQL Server using kerberos authentication, We are using SQL Server 2012 Express, How we can implement this?

Comment: What about putting `SQL Server 2012 express kerberos java` to Google?

Comment: While google we are getting old informations related to SQL Server 2003, We are using SQL Server 2012, When we tried to run query  " select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid"  for verify SQL Server can be run via Kerberos return only NTLM, So we need to know how we can enable kerberos in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

From [Understanding Kerberos and NTLM authentication in SQL Server Connections](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections/)

Kerberos, several aspects needed:

1) Client and Server must join a domain, and the trusted third party exists; if client and server are in different domain, these two domains must be configured as two-way trust.

2) Registered SPN. Service Principal Name(SPNs) are unique identifiers for services running on servers. Each service  that will use Kerberos authentication needs to have an SPN set for it so that clients can identify the service on the network. It is registered in Active Directory under either a computer account or a user account.

Service Principal Name

An SPN for SQL Server is composed of the following elements:

• ServiceClass: This identifies the general class of service. This is always MSSQLSvc for SQL Server. 
   • Host: This is the fully qualified domain name DNS of the computer that is running SQL Server. 
   • Port: This is the port number that the service is listening on.

```
 eg:  MSSQLSvc/myserver.corp.mycomany.com:1433
```

Comment: This solution based on SQL Server 2005, We are using SQL Server 2012, When we tried to run query  " select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid"  for verify SQL Server can be run via Kerberos return only NTLM, So we need to know how we can enable kerberos in SQL Server 2012

Comment: You have to run the query remotely..not by logging into same box

Comment: Now we are getting the following Exception,

   **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:01fc986b-cf00-4d68-883c-f6871e121637**   , 

We set the SPN = MSSQLSvc/SUGARSERVER.Sugar.local:1433,

Our connection String is,

  `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  String jdbcString = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.54:1433;serverSpn=MSSQLSvc/SUGARSERVER.Sugar.local:1433;databaseName=SSUnit1PS;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcString);`